# Spring Websocket (ActiveMQ): Stomp subscribe and get messages enqueued from a Topic

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

I am working with `Spring WebSocket` and `Stomp`.

**Note**: the broker is `ActiveMQ`

I have two `@Schedule` methods that sends messages to `Queue` and `Topic` respectively

For a subscription for a `Queue`, the code is as follows:

```
$('#ws_connect').click(function(){

    console.log('Connect clicked');

    var socket = new SockJS('/project-app/ws/notification');

    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        $('#notification').append('<p>Connected</p>');
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/somedestination', function (notification) {
            ... append the content to the html page, it works
        });
    });

});
```

If there is no user the `Queue` is getting message by message. Once the user arrives and do the connection, automatically it gets all the *messages enqueued* and the `Queue` pass to be empty. If a new message arrives it appears automatically, it because the user remains connected yet. If the user disconnects and later do the connection, it can see again all the *messages enqueued*. Until here all is Ok

As follows for a subscription for a `Topic`

```
$('#ws_connect').click(function(){

    console.log('Connect clicked');

    var socket = new SockJS('/project-app/ws/notification');

    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        $('#notification').append('<p>Connected</p>');
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/somedestination', function (notification) {
            ... append the content to the html page, it works
        });
    });

});
```

Practically the `js` code is the same than the `Queue` version. Just the destination is different.

Here the **problem** is that if exists *messages enqueued* in the `Topic` and if the user does the connection the messages do not appear automatically. Of course meanwhile the user remains connected he can see each new message, same case if multiple users are connected to the same `Topic` all can see the same new message.

But again for the first user to connect to the `Topic` destination. He is not able to get the *messages enqueued* from that `Topic` when he does the connection.

- Is it the normal behaviour?
- How can be retrieved the *messages enqueued*?
- Perhaps a suggested approach to handle this scenario? 
  In some way the "worst" scenario would be create multiple `Queue`s for each potential user. But just curious if through `Topic` is possible get this requeriment

Answer (score 1):

The Topic destination does not store messages when there are no subscribers so the code is working as expected.  The only time a Topic would retain messages for subscribers is if the subscriber had created a durable topic subscription and then gone offline at which point the broker would store any message sent to the Topic with the persistent flag enabled.  The caveat here being that any message sent to that Topic before the subscription is made would be dropped.

See the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html) for more help.

Comment: I understand. Thus all the already `messages enqueued` that are reported through the `ActiveMQ Web Console` for that `Topic` are practically totally abandoned. Thus seems the best approach is have multiple `Queue`s

Comment: The enqueued count simply gives you some insight into how many messages have been fired at the Topic, but the mechanics of a Topic are defined by the JMS specification so crying about it won't help.